# Discord.js - Is there a way to check a decibels level in a discord call?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to make a bot that plays audios depending on the amount of decibels people are making on the call, any idea if it's possible or how to do this with discord.js?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way for a bot to collect audio data from a call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried this in the past.

None of my solutions worked after tens of hours of research and testing, but it might work for you if you have more time/knowledge. Here's what I tried if you want a starting point:

1. Decoding the audio bitstream into raw pcm, and reading the buffer to find the amplitude (little-endian vs big-endian is important).
2. Piping the stream into ffmpeg and using a filter like [ebur128](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/ebur128.htm.gz) to get the audio level (using encoded and decoded audio, when I tried this, it was able to distinguish between whispering and talking, but not talking and yelling).

Good luck if you choose to pursue this.